# How to calculate receiving shadow?

Tags: cesium, solar-radiation, shadow

Using the Cesium library, I want to find shadows that objects fall onto each other. With Cesium, I can create shadows of objects, but I have no idea how to get the shadows that fall on objects.

How can I obtain the areas of the resulting shadows? How can I calculate the amount of shadows or amount of light falling on objects?